# Rails 3 associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :book_users
  has_many :books, :through => :book_users
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :book_users
  has_many :users, :through => :book_users
end
```

An user can write many books
An book can belong to only one user
An user can be a reader of different books
An book can be read by different users

```
User.books
```

should give me the books the user has written

```
User.books_read
```

should give me the books, are read by this user

How accomplish this ?

Second question, what is the simplest method to delete book_read from the user ?
I mean

```
User.method_name(book_id) # what's the method name ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**

You either use `:source` or `:class_name`.

```
has_many :books_read, :class_name => "Book", :through => :book_users
```

I don't know for sure if `:class_name` works with `has_many :through`. If it doesn't work, try this:

```
has_many :books_read, :source => :book, :through => :book_users
```

That should do the trick.

**Second question:**

As far as I know there isn't really a simple method to delete books from the books_read relation. You could create your own method to accomplish this. Just make sure you delete records from `:book_users` and not the `has_many :through` relation. Or else the books themselves will be deleted.

```
def delete_book(book_id)
  self.book_users.find_by_book_id(book_id).destroy
end
```

When using Rails 3 you can't use the `find_by_...` helper and need to use `where`.

```
def delete_book(book_id)
  self.book_users.where(:book_id => book_id).destroy
end
```

Now you can call this function as follows:

```
User.find(1).delete_book(2)
```

I hope that helps you out.